# Can we have a green or red mark in our profiles to show if we're online or offline?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

It would be nice if user profiles have green or red circle to show whether they are online or offline.
Can we have this feature please?

Comment: What do you mean by *offline*? Logged out from all devices? And why would a specific user being "offline" or not matter?

Comment: Why would anyone ever go offline from Stack Overflow? My sock puppet scripts might stop working!

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I mean Currently on the site or not

Comment: @machine_1, how is the system supposed to know that?

Comment: what's the benefit of this, really?

Comment: when you visit someone's profile,instead of staring at the statement "last seen ...",you can know immediately if he'es on site or not

Comment: I'm technically authenticated on four devices, but I'm not online at any given moment in time.  Why would this be useful?

Comment: @Machine_1 yeah, you would know if they are on site. But that's a tautology if I'm asking what the benefit is... I ask what's good, you say "It would be good to see if they are, because I could know if they are"...

Comment: Well,I proposed it.You refused it.It is still a nice feature.

Comment: @machine_1 You can always check the _last seen_ state of a particular user, that's pretty much good enough to see if the user is (currently) active.

Comment: @machine_1 no, I didn't refuse or approve. I'm still at the point of "what's the benefit there". Because so far you offer little in that regard

Comment: Note that feature requests really need to be fleshed out in terms of pros and cons, costs and benefits. Why should Stack Overflow build this feature for us? How would it help? If possible, demonstrate the need with actual data.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This would be fundamentally against the philosophy of Stack Overflow.

The entire nature of SO is asynchronous - there's no "live" communication, but bits and pieces piling on top of each other whenever people have "a slice of time" for it, as the site's founders once put it.

That's also why questions can't be addressed to a single user. Questions are presented to the *community*, and *someone* will answer it. *Someone else* will edit the answer, or comment on it, or add an answer of their own...

For neither of this is it relevant to know whether a specific is online *right now*.

The "last seen" field is arguably a valid exception to the philosophy, for entirely practical everyday reasons. It allows you to see whether a user can have seen your edit or comment, for example.

One possible way a "user is online" indicator could be used is that you can, say, ask a C# question knowing that Jon Skeet is online *right now* and there's a chance he might see it.

But we explicitly and strongly discourage this kind of targeting specific users.

Comment: No live communication, minus the chat rooms ;-)

Comment: I don't see how the indicator would help with Jon Skeet, he sees everything.

Comment: -1 because jon sees all the content, onlne or not.

Comment: @TravisJ, Magisch - I'm not sure what I was thinking. Will fix right away

Comment: @CubeJockey yeah, excepting chat of course.